# Uncountably infinite set between 1-2 and 1-10?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Just a quick question:

Is the size of the set of real numbers from 1 to 2 greater, or equal in size to the number of real numbers between 1 and 10?

I'm a Physicist so I'm not totally clued up on Mathematical jargon pertaining to set theory...

Comment: Perhaps a more interesting example would be that $[0,1]$ and $\mathbb R^\infty$ (meaning $\mathbb R\cup\mathbb R^2\cup\mathbb R^3\cup\ldots$) have the same size. But you shouldn't really care about that as a physicist.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They're equal. Indeed, it's not too hard to show that the function $f\colon [1, 2] \to [1, 10]$ defined by:
$$
f(x) = 9x - 8
$$
is a bijection (which shows that the two sets have equal cardinality).

Comment: Awesome, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

If $ a < b$ and $c < d $ then $card ([a,b]) = card ([c,d]) $

Proof : define $ f :[a,b]\to [c,d]$

$f(x)= \frac{d-c}{b-a}x- \frac{a(d-c)-c(b-a)}{b-a}$, $f$ is bijection so the proof is complete.